# What tools are used for the preparation of grain boundary models?

Tags: software, grain-boundaries

What methods and tools are used for building models of grain boundaries?
I mean initial models that are then optimized using molecular dynamics potentials or a different methods.

When I was involved in such things 10-15 years ago we were writing own codes to generate starting structures. Both big systems that emulated nano-sized policrystals

[image: policrystal]

and small bicrystals to analyze particular boundary types

[image: bicrystal]

(I added pictures to clarify what type of things I'm writing about)

I wonder what tools (if any) are used nowadays?

Comment: Czeszc Marcin! "grain-boundaries" is one of the only tags we don't have a description for yet, would you mind filling it out here? https://materials.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/26 Your edit will be placed in a queue and I will accept it if it makes sense :)

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking for generating synthesized microstructures for using it in Phase-Field simulation, the best choice is [Dream 3D](http://dream3d.bluequartz.net/), where you can control the distribution of grains and their crystallographic orientations:

[image]

If you are looking for a framework to generate synthesized polycrystalline structures for molecular dynamics simulation, the best tool is [Atomsk](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/), that is compatible with LAMMPS, DL_POLY, VASP, QuantumEspresso, SIESTA, etc.:

[image]

Comment: Can Atomsk generate bicrystal models for analysing particular types of grain boundaries like CSL/special boundaries ($\Sigma 3$, $\Sigma 5$, etc.)?

Comment: @Mythreyi Not directly as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

Alone Programmer's [answer](https://materials.stackexchange.com/a/395/22) already mentions ways to generate polycrystalline microstructure. To add to that, it is possible to generate models of bi-crystals to analyse particular grain boundaries directly using LAMMPS. [Here](https://icme.hpc.msstate.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Grain_boundary_generation) is a detailed wiki on how to generate such models.

Apart from this, there was a Java based applet called [GBStudio](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/matertrans/47/11/47_11_2706/_article) that made generating grain boundary models very simple. Unfortunately, this tool seems to be no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

In 2008 I wrote a Python script to generate bicrystal models in a PBC box.
Since the boundary is periodic (due to PBC), it's always a coincidence site lattice (CSL) boundary.

[image]

The script is in repository named [gosam](https://github.com/wojdyr/gosam)
and is [documented here](https://github.com/wojdyr/gosam/wiki#bicrystalpy).

The math was based on H. Grimmer's paper ["The generating function for coincidence site lattices in the cubic system"](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108767384000246),
so it works only for cubic lattices.

From time to time (maybe once every two years) I get a question from someone trying to use this script. Unfortunately, I don't remember much and I can only answer simple questions.